# How to fill a empty php form value with a default value

Tags: php, forms

I have a form I am trying to fill dynamically but if it does not have a value I want it to assign a default value. Here is my code I currently have the field name is referrer:

```
$jsession = \JFactory::getSession();
$referrer = $jsession->get('referrer', ''); 
// if there is no saved value but there is one in the form data - save it
if (empty($referrer) && !empty($form->data['referrer'])) {
    $referrer = $form->data['referrer'];
    $jsession->set('referrer', $referrer);
}
$form->data['referrer'] = $referrer;
```

How can I set a default value in the form input if the value is empty?

Comment: What is your problem/question?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I set a default value in the form input if the value is empty?

Comment: where you want to set empty value, means to which value

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter on `$form '#default_value'` and then set its value to the following:

```
$form["field_accounts"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $default;
```

Comment: But how would that get assigned to the field "referrer" that I need it assigned to?